# How does url rewrite works?

Tags: http, url-rewriting, webserver

How does web server implements url rewrite mechanism and changes the address bar of browsers?
I'm not asking specific information to configure apache, nginx, lighthttpd or other!
I would like to know what kind of information is sent to clients when servers want rewrite url?